# avoid jdbc batch insert failure if one record failed to insert in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate

The Oracle JDBC driver throws a BatchUpdateException if an error occurs in the middle of the batch. Using NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport to insert data as below

```
getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(query, dataList, 1000,
  new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<MyObject>() {
     @Override
     public void setValues(final PreparedStatement ps, final MyObject bucket) throws SQLException {
       ps.setString(1, bucket.getInit());
       ps.setString(2, bucket.getNbr());                  
    }
});
```

I'm running into BatchUpdateException because of unique key constraint, we are processing millions of records so we can't go to database to check unique key.

Is there anyway that batch insert won't fails if one record failed.

Comment: Is there some way you can scrub your data before even sending it to Oracle such that a failure like this would be very improbable?

Comment: as we are processing millions of records, we don't know which record is duplicate.. if it is null pointer or like exceptions we can handle in code only

Comment: I don't have an answer then.  Maybe use smaller batches, such that if one batch fails, you don't have to rollback everything.

Comment: yeah i will take your suggestion.. try to remove failed record from batch and insert again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG) hint.
add a comment after the insert, like this.

```
insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(table_name, unique_index_name) */
       (...)
```

But if you're inserting a million rows this way you're likely better off using sqlldr.